# Создание grpc сервера с ssl шифрованием

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc

Создаю сервер grpc:

```
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions credential_options;
credential_options.force_client_auth = true;

const std::string private_key = read_file("server.key");
const std::string cert_chain =  read_file("server.crt");
credential_options.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back({private_key, cert_chain});

auto channel_credentials = grpc::SslServerCredentials( credential_options );
builder.AddListeningPort(StateService::instance().ipAddress(), channel_credentials);
builder.RegisterService(grpcLocalService_.get());
server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
```

ключ и сертификат создаю скриптом:

```
mypass="pass123"

echo Generate server key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:$mypass -des3 -out server.key 4096

echo Generate server signing request:
openssl req -passin pass:$mypass -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Google/OU=youtube/CN=localhost"

echo Self-sign server certificate:
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:$mypass -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

echo Remove passphrase from server key:
openssl rsa -passin pass:$mypass -in server.key -out server.key

rm server.csr
```

При запуске приложения получаю следующее:

> E0813 19:24:39.571705892   21058 ssl_transport_security.c:628] Invalid cert chain file.

> E0813 19:24:39.571727037   21058 security_connector.c:893]   Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.

> E0813 19:24:39.571736766   21058 server_secure_chttp2.c:96]  {"created":"@1597321479.571730594","description":"Unable to create secure server with credentials of type Ssl.","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure/server_secure_chttp2.c","file_line":75,"security_status":1}

Я правильно понимаю в `grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair` нужно передавать содержимое файлов `.key` и `.crt`, а не имя файлов? Если да то как их нужно считывать?

```
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 MIIFMDCCAxgCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwXjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNV
 ...// лишние строки убрал для краткости
 BAgMAkNBMQ4wDAYDVQQHDAVUb21zazEOMAwGA1UECgwFRWxlc3kxDjAMBgNVBAsM
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

пропуская первую и последнюю строки или нет?

Но в любом случае ошибка все таже  `Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.`

Comment: `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` почти наверняка нужно оставить т.к. похоже эти ключи напрямую в openssl'евские `PEM_*` функции передаются, а они AFAIK их требуют... по проблеме — я бы собрал `grpc` с отладочной информацией и просто отладчиком поискал бы, с какого места он возвращает ошибку...

Comment: собственно, если верить [этому](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/6f5c468dfe2277151f4266338eb36d7c9cf4124e/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc#L1888), то скорей всего надо задать корневой сертификат в `credential_options.pem_root_certs`... поидей должен быть тот же самый `server.crt`, хотя я не уверен — я не видел, чтобы корневой сертификат подписывали самим собой и использовали для шифрования — обычно для этого создают отдельную пару, так что у меня есть сомнения, что это правильно... ЗЫ: ну и хранить в обычном `std::string` секретный ключ — не самая светлая идея с точки зрения паранойи...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В структуру `grpc::SslServerCredentialOptions::PemKeyCertPair` нужно передавать содержимое файлов ключа и сертификата полностью.

Как было указано в коментариях к вопросу нужно задать корневой сертификат
в `credential_options.pem_root_certs`.  Сертификаты и ключи я генерировал скриптом взятым [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714558/how-to-enable-server-side-ssl-for-grpc)

```
  @echo off
  set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg

  echo Generate CA key:
  openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out ca.key 4096

  echo Generate CA certificate:
  openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=MyRootCA"

  echo Generate server key:
  openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out server.key 4096

  echo Generate server signing request:
  openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=localhost"

 echo Self-sign server certificate:
 openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1111 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

 echo Remove passphrase from server key:
 openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in server.key -out server.key

 echo Generate client key
 openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out client.key 4096

 echo Generate client signing request:
 openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=%CLIENT-COMPUTERNAME%"

 echo Self-sign client certificate:
 openssl x509 -passin pass:1111 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

 echo Remove passphrase from client key:
 openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in client.key -out client.key
```